# Difference between match and match with where

Tags: neo4j, match, where-clause

Simple question about difference queries (especially performance) below:

```
MATCH (n { name:"X" }) RETURN n;
```

and

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.name="X" RETURN n;
```

Comment: in both cases you should use a Label which would Neo4j to allow indexes. e.g. `MATCH (n:User { name:"X" }) RETURN n;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first style is more readable, but limits you to testing for equality of one or more scalar (non-array) properties.

The second style is less readable, but lets you use the full power of Cypher predicates.

In terms of performance. there is really no difference.

Comment: Was this anything you measured outright, or was this something you've noticed through everyday use? For my current use case, it doesn't matter which I use, but it's interesting to keep in mind for future best practices, and the documentation is thin on this point. Tnx.