# Semantic difference between "match pattern1, pattern2" and match "match pattern1 where pattern2"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have those two queries:

Query A

```
match 
(r:report)-[:NEXTUPDATE*]->(u1:severity {what:'normal'})-[:NEXTUPDATE*]->(u2:severity {what: 'critical'}),
(r)-[:NEXTUPDATE*]->(:resolution)
return r, u1, u2
```

Query B

```
match 
(r:report)-[:NEXTUPDATE*]->(u1:severity {what:'normal'})-[:NEXTUPDATE*]->(u2:severity {what: 'critical'})
where (r)-[:NEXTUPDATE*]->(:resolution) 
return r, u1, u2
```

The only difference between these queries is that Query B uses a 'where' instead of a comma to seperate the two patterns.

I had assumed that they would produce identical results, but they don't. 
Query A returns 0 rows; Query B returns the expected result of 1212 results.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824349/difference-between-match-and-match-with-where) and it's answer lead me to believe that it does not make a difference whether a pattern is in the `match` or in the `where` part of a query.

Obviously, I must have misunderstood something, or created a corner case. My best attempt at an explanation is that both patterns take the same path in my model and this somehow is a problem if both patterns exist in the `match` part.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your two queries are vastly different. Your first query simultaneously matches two things and has no restrictions placed on it. Wheras your second query matches one thing and then filters the results with a where condition.

In your first query you are generating a cartesian product by asking it to match all of the reports that have a normal severity followed by a critical severity in a variable length path.

`(r:report)-[:NEXTUPDATE*]->(u1:severity {what:'normal'})-[:NEXTUPDATE*]->(u2:severity {what: 'critical'})`

and for every one of those matching all of the reports with resolutions

`(r)-[:NEXTUPDATE*]->(:resolution)`

as a result you will return the number of rows that match the first part times the number of rows that match the second part.

In your second query you are asking for the same report but also placing the restriction on it that it must also have a resolution.

If you wanted the first one to work like the second on you could do something like this...

```
match (r:report)-[:NEXTUPDATE*]->(u1:severity {what:'normal'})-[:NEXTUPDATE*]->(u2:severity {what: 'critical'})
with r, u1, u2
match r-[:NEXTUPDATE*]->(:resolution)
return r, u1, u2
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. If Query A generates a cartesian product why does it return 0 rows? I would expect to drown in returned rows.